# Is there an analogue of Ruby gsub method in Perl?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I perform a Perl substitution on a string while keeping the original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836/how-do-i-perform-a-perl-substitution-on-a-string-while-keeping-the-original)

How do I do one line replacements in Perl without modifying the string itself? I also want it to be usable inside expressions, much like I can do `p s.gsub(/from/, 'to')` in Ruby.

All I can think of is

```
do {my $r = $s; $r =~ s/from/to/; $r}
```

but sure there is a better way?

Comment: @ephemient => the linked question does not cover using the substitution as a subexpression

Comment: @Eric: Sure it does.  One of the answers mentions the new `/r` option in Perl 5.13.2 (which will make it into Perl 5.14).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you found with `do` is not bad, but you can shorten it a little:

```
do {(my $r = $s) =~ s/from/to/; $r}
```

It still reveals the mechanics though. You can hide the implementation, and also apply substitutions to lists by writing a subroutine.  In most implementations, this function is called `apply` which you could import from [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) or [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils) or a number of other modules.  Or since it is so short, just write it yourself:

```
sub apply (&@) {                  # takes code block `&` and list `@`
    my ($sub, @ret) = @_;         # shallow copy of argument list 
    $sub->() for @ret;            # apply code to each copy
    wantarray ? @ret : pop @ret   # list in list context, last elem in scalar
}
```

`apply` creates a shallow copy of the argument list, and then calls its code block, which is expected to modify `$_`.  The block's return value is not used.  `apply` behaves like the comma `,` operator.  In list context, it returns the list.  In scalar context, it returns the last item in the list.

To use it:

```
my $new = apply {s/foo/bar/} $old;

my @new = apply {s/foo/bar/} qw( foot fool fooz );
```

Comment: And, Perl 5.14 adds the /r substitution modifier to work on a copy and return the result so the original stays the same: http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/659

Answer (score 10):

Starting on the day you feel comfortable writing `use 5.14.0` at the top of all of your programs, you can use the [s/foo/bar/r](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.13.9/pod/perl5132delta.pod#Non-destructive_substitution) variant of the `s///` operator, which returns the changed string instead of modifying the original in place (added in perl 5.13.2).

Comment: Unfortunately we stuck in middle ages with 5.8.8. Big companies do not like to move forward.

Comment: Wait, what?  I thought it was supposed to modify and return?

Comment: @ysth not unless the delta and the 5.13 `perlrequick` are both lying :)

Comment: As always: The Effective Perler http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/659

Answer (score 3):

From [Perl's docs: Regexp-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

`($foo = $bar) =~ s/this/that/g;    # copy first, then change` would match `gsub`, while
`$bar =~ s/this/that/g; # change` would match `gsub!`

Comment: it won't give me string back so it can't be used inside expressions.

Comment: if used in a scalar context, then a comma followed by the var: `...,$foo` will do that