# Using Perl to rename files in windows

Tags: windows, perl

My program needs to rename files that end like this

file(1)
file(2)
file(3)

I want them to be renamed to this

file_1
file_2
file_3

I attempted this in c++ but that does not seem efficient. I think Perl would be great for it but do not know where to start even.

Comment: Those are strange file names: Windows file names almost always have a file type Are you sure they're not `file(1).txt`, `file(2).txt`, `file(3).txt` etc. or something similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use File-Rename aka Perl's rename in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75214132/how-to-use-file-rename-aka-perls-rename-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir =       'folder';
my @dir =       ();

opendir(DIR, $dir);
@dir    =       readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

foreach my $file (@dir) {
    my $f=$file;
    $f =~ s/\(/_/;
    $f =~ s/\)//;
    rename "$dir/$file", "$dir/$f";
}
```

The `\(` in `s/\(/_/` is matching the "(" in the filename `file(1)` and replacing with "_", so `$f =~ s/\(/_/;` makes `$f` become `file_1)`. The `\)` in `s/\)//` is matching the ")" in the filename `file_1)` and replacing with "" (nothing), so `$f =~ s/\)//;` makes `$f` become `file_1`.

Comment: For keep the original data, use non destructive modifier. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836/how-do-i-perform-a-perl-substitution-on-a-string-while-keeping-the-original)

Comment: I would probably do $f =~ s/\((\d+)\)/_$1/g; instead. Does it in one line.

Comment: Ya im not sure who down voted. Thanks for the input everyone, I will be studying this closely until I can read it better. BTW this is not an assignment, but my own personal interest/use.

Comment: $f =~ s/((\d+))/_$1/g;# So this line I believe says: substitute any digit of one or more in parenthesis with an underscore and the capture variable $1 which is the number in the parenthesis. and the g allows for global matching, which im not sure exactly why we need at at this moment.

Comment: Also I am testing this out and the testfile(1) turns into testfile(_1) but this doesnt make since because of the double parenthesis in the regular expression. I took a pair of the parenthesis away and it seemed to make no difference do I need to use \((d+)\) or something?

edit: I cant put \'s behind my parenthesis in my comments here

Comment: @stackoverfloweth In what way? You even copied it and told him to try it.

Comment: @kchinger, did you escape the "(" by using `\(` because you have `/((\d+))/` when it should be `/\((\d+)\)/`.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Oops, copied it wrong. I'll edit it. It was right in my notepad++ when I tested it but I typed it wrong here instead of copying I guess.

Comment: Why use your own version of `rename` ? `file-rename` can be downloaded as well, or [the simple script from Larry Wall](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/perl-rename/master/rename)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is **Where to start?** So start the perl from [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/)

For file rename take a look at [Here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html).

For  open the directory and for read , look at [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html).

And then also look at here for [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).