# Print numbers, upper-lower case letters separately in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list like:

```
 DD2aaQQmmm
 AA34DDmm
```

And i want to print the upper case, the lower case and the numbers separately, so it would be like:

```
DDQQ aammm 2
AADD mm 34
```

How should I do this in perl, using regex?

I have tried for the upper case this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array = <>;
chomp(@array);

foreach (@array){
    if ($_ = ~ /([A-Z][a-z])/){
        print $_ "\n"
    }
}
```

But this only prints out the words starts with upper case.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself before you posted?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar Bears solution is absolutely correct - but needs perl 5.14+ Here is a simple workaround for older perl versions.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    my @out = ($line, $line, $line); 
    $out[0] =~ s/[^A-Z]//g;
    $out[1] =~ s/[^a-z]//g;
    $out[2] =~ s/[^0-9]//g;
    print join(' ', @out) . "\n";
}

__DATA__
DD2aaQQmmm
 AA34DDmm
```

Answer (score 3):

The task is quite simple -- separate the wheat from the chaff

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    my @out;
    $out[0] = $line =~ s/[^A-Z]//gr;
    $out[1] = $line =~ s/[^a-z]//gr;
    $out[2] = $line =~ s/[^0-9]//gr;
    say join(' ', @out);
}

__DATA__
DD2aaQQmmm
 AA34DDmm
```

Output

```
DDQQ aammm 2
AADD mm 34
```

Of cause the final script can read from pipe or file given on command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while(<>) {
    my @out;
    $out[0] = s/[^A-Z]//gr;
    $out[1] = s/[^a-z]//gr;
    $out[2] = s/[^0-9]//gr;
    say join(' ', @out);
}
```

Comment: This is correct - but difficult to read imho. Using `my @out = ($line, $line, $line); $out[0] =~ s/...` would take *me* less time to understand this code.

Comment: @GeorgMavridis -- three extra useless copies, more work for nothing. (Imagine a brick layer going for each brick to ground floor to pick it up and bring to work place).

Comment: I dont know why, but as an output I only get "1 1 1".

Comment: What is your perl version? In perl 5.14.0 or later, you can use the new /r  ... Please check ulr https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836/how-do-i-perform-a-perl-substitution-on-a-string-while-keeping-the-original

Comment: @PolarBear -- the usage of the /r modifier which causes the result of the substitution to be *returned* instead of modifying the underlying variable, is something not expected by *me* and thus not easy for *me* to read.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go is to use [tr operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlop.html).

```
use Modern::Perl;

while(my $str = <DATA>) {
    chomp $str;
    my @out;
    push @out, $str =~ tr/A-Z//cdr;
    push @out, $str =~ tr/a-z//cdr;
    push @out, $str =~ tr/0-9//cdr;
    say "@out";
}

__DATA__
DD2aaQQmmm
 AA34DDmm
```

**Output:**

```
DDQQ aammm 2
AADD mm 34
```

`tr` is about 6 times quicker than `s///`, here is a benchmarck:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $str = "DD2aaQQmmm";

my $count = -3;
cmpthese($count, {
    'tr' => sub {
        my @out; 
        push @out, $str =~ tr/A-Z//cdr;
        push @out, $str =~ tr/a-z//cdr;
        push @out, $str =~ tr/0-9//cdr;
    },
    'subst' => sub {
        my @out;
        $out[0] = $str =~ s/[^A-Z]//gr;
        $out[1] = $str =~ s/[^a-z]//gr;
        $out[2] = $str =~ s/[^0-9]//gr;
    },
});
```

**Output:**

```
          Rate subst    tr
subst  58165/s    --  -84%
tr    357629/s  515%    --
```